# How to use ActiveDataProvider with select2?

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to use the jquery-select2 (loading remote data) plugin with Yii2 search model. As of right now, my controller returns the $dataProvider created from the search model. However, it is obviously not in a format that select2 can use to create the drop down.

What do I need to do to $dataProvider or select2 to get the two to work together?

The way I see it, there are 2 options:

1. Extract the 'cat_name' from $dataProvider and put it in a format that select2 can use.
2. Teach select2 how to read the $dataProvider.

I'm not sure how I would do 2 and I suspect that it would make the 'tagging' functionality difficult to implement, thus I'm leaning towards 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

Controller side

```
public function actionCatSearch($q)
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        $searchModel = new CatSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['catSearch' => ['cat_name' => $q]]);

        return $dataProvider->models;


    }
}
```

JS side

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('.js-select').select2({
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'cat-search',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while, but I managed to figure it out. There are a couple of things that need to happen. First, use the built in serializer from Yii2, then `json_encode` the results.

On the script side, I had to use `templateResult`.

Here is everything modified:

Controller side

```
public function actionCatSearch($q)
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        $searchModel = new CatSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['catSearch' => ['cat_name' => $q]]);

        $serial = new Serializer();
        $test = $serial->serialize($dataProvider);

        return json_encode($test);

    }
}
```

Script side

```
function formatStuff (stuff) {
  if (stuff.loading) return 'Searching...';

  markup = "<p>" + stuff.cat_name + "</p>";

  return markup;
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('.js-select').select2({
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'cat-search',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatStuff,
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the column you need from the models

```
 public function actionCatSearch($q)
 {
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

       $searchModel = new CatSearch();
       $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['catSearch' => ['cat_name' => $q]]);

       $cat_name = array_column($dataProvider->models, 'cat_name');
       return json_encode($cat_name); 

   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it yielded an empty result for me.

Comment: try return without json_encode, try or var_dump the value of $cat_name, $dataProvider->models, try for find where is problem